# Add active class to Bootstraps 4 dropdown when open and remove when closed

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I was wondering if there is a way to add an active class to Bootstraps 4 dropdown handle when dropdown is open? I know that class 'show' is being added but this class is also added to dropdown-menu. So would like to add new class just to 'dropdown' Can't figure it out.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown link
  </a>

  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It already does this it adds the class of .show when it is opened are you trying to add another class?

Comment: wow :) you are not wrong. I think I work too much lol

Comment: the thing is class show is also being added to dropdown-menu so need extra class so I could style 'dropdown' handle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap already adds and removes a class to the dropdown and the dropdown-menu when it is open.  It gives it the class of `.show`.  If you want to target the whole dropdown you can target it like so:

```
.dropdown.show
```

If you want to target the button then you can use

```
.dropdown.show .btn
```

If you want to target the dropdown menu u can use

```
.dropdown-menu.show
```